# In a trapezium DEBC, with diagonals BE and DC, the area of triangle DEB = area of triangle DEC.

Tags: geometry, plane-geometry

Why is this so? I understand that they share a common length DE and that the perpendicular from B to DE = the perpendicular from C to DE. Am I missing something?

edit: DE // BC

Comment: `I understand that they share a common length DE and that the perpendicular from B to DE = the perpendicular from C to DE.` You got both of those right. `Am I missing something?` Well, isn't the area of a triangle related to base and height somehow?

Comment: If DE is shorter than BC, wouldn't making a perpendicular from B to DE and C to DE change the length of DE?

Comment: Drawing an altitude in a triangle can never change the length of the opposite side. How could it?

Comment: I'm sorry if I sound stupid, but doesn't drawing a perpendicular from B to DE imply that I will be drawing it to a non-existent line?

Comment: The ***line*** $DE$ is infinite in both directions, and the perpendicular is drawn to the ***line***. The length of the side $DE$ of the triangle is the length of ***segment*** $DE$, which doesn't change regardless of whether the foot of the altitude falls within it, or outside it.

Comment: Oh of course! That makes sense, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

The area of the triangle is $\frac{1}{2}\times base \times height$. Since length of the base and height are same for both the triangles the area is also same.